# mTLS from Istio Gateway to upstream workload not working

Tags: istio, istio-gateway, istio-sidecar

I am unable to get mTLS working between an Istio Gateway and a workload within my mesh. I get the following error when calling from the Istio Gateway to the target service:

```
curl http://target-service.default
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

I have an Istio Gateway installed in the `istio-system` namespace.  I also have a workload installed in the `default` namespace.  The traffic flow looks like this:

`Inbound traffic => Istio Gateway (istio-system ns) => Target Service (default ns)`

I have applied `PeerAuthentication` in the `default` namespace for mtls

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: PeerAuthentication
metadata:
  name: default
  namespace: default
spec:
  mtls:
    mode: STRICT
```

I am able to access the target workload using mTLS from other pods, it is only the Istio Gateway that is unable to do so.  I have `auto-injection` turned on for the Istio Gateway and it appears to be working fine.  Other workloads within the `istio-system` namespace can access the target service, only the Istio Gateway cannot.

I want to make sure the traffic from the Gateway to the target service is encrypted.  Any input would be much appreicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've got this working now.  I had FluxCD installed and I think it was messing things up.  Wireshark is showing encryption between the gateway and the target pod now.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing this issue regardless of the mTLS peerauthentication configuration - I was using AWS EKS, with kubernetes version 1.26.

What was causing this issue for me was that on the node group level, there wasn't a security group rule that allowed all the traffic within the SG - Basically all traffic should be allowed within the node group - ref https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/sec-group-reqs.html .

Once i enabled that rule, my applications started working fine.
Let me know if that helps

Comment: Thanks for posting @Srikar.  My EKS node security group is already open to all internal traffic so this doesn't solve it for me.  Also, I'm only seeing this issue with mTLS enabled.  With mTLS disabled I don't run into this error at all.  Thank you.